# Time difference between consecutive points QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a shapefile with a timestamp (string type) and id field (string type):

```
timestamp             tag  id
2017-11-14 09:03:00    1    0
2017-11-14 13:03:00    1    1
2017-11-14 20:03:00    1    2
2017-11-14 09:03:00    2    3
2017-11-14 13:03:00    2    4
```

I'm trying to find the time difference in hours between consecutive points by id using the Field Calculator tool in QGIS.

I tried the following expression but the results returned `NULL`. When I try to convert the timestamp field to DateTime using to_datetime function I get an error that it can not convert to DateTime. Any other suggestions on calculating the time difference with the Field Calculator in QGIS?

```
 second(age(attribute($currentfeature, to_datetime(timestamp)), 
           attribute(get_feature_by_id('points',$id-1), to_datetime(timestamp))))
```

Comment: Your timestamp can't be directly converted to a datetime object, look at the datetime object in python https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects , you will need to split your string to create a datetime object (to create one use datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond, tzinfo, *, fold)), subtract one from the other and you will have a timedelta object https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects which can then be expressed as days, hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it:

```
hour(age(
 to_datetime(attribute($currentfeature,'timestamp')),
 to_datetime(attribute(get_feature_by_id('points',$id-1),'timestamp'))
))
```

Results are in **hours** as specified.
In my case, I used this to populate a column **"timedif"**:

[image: Time difference result]

---

Difference in **seconds** would be:

```
second(age(
 to_datetime(attribute($currentfeature,'timestamp')),
 to_datetime(attribute(get_feature_by_id('points',$id-1),'timestamp'))
))
```